# Counter in verilog

Tags: verilog, clock, counter, hdl, quartus

i want to make a counter that increases by the value of its inputs, but i did the testbench and the output is undetermined, xxxx.
Can someone tell me if there is something wrong in this code?

```
    //Count

 module count(clk, 

 rst, val, coin


 );
//Declaración entradas y salidas

 input  clk, rst;
 input  [3:0] coin;
 output [3:0] val;

 reg [3:0] val;  
 reg [3:0] nval; 


 always @(posedge clk, negedge rst)
      if(rst == 0) val <= 4'b0000;
      else val <= nval;

    always @(val)
      nval <= val + coin ;
  endmodule
```

Comment: I mostly using VHDL, and my verilog is very rusty, but it seems weird to me that you declare an output called val, and a reg called val as well. If that's legal in Verilog, my apologies. Might be worth using different name for clarity anyway.

Comment: This is where you learn to debug.

Comment: @MAB i understand your point. In fact what i was trying to do was to declare the output as a reg but it might be wrong. Thank you anyways, i'm going to check it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning initial value to *nval* anywhere, so all further values depends on this, therefore *val* is undetermined.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to be sure without testing that there is nothing else, but I think it's this

```
always @(val)
   nval <= val + coin ;
```

As a non=blocking assignment, it will possibly take the old value of val (i.e. X) at reset. You could use a blocking assignment, and fill out the sensitivity list properly:

```
always @(val or coin)
   nval = val + coin;
```

or use an assign:

```
wire [3:0] nval;
assign nval = val + coin;
```

Doing anything else is likely to cause problems (if not here, with other code).